# Search for all strings encased in ## ... ## in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a program that can read variables from a template and allow the user to edit them. I'm trying to use regex to find instances of user-defined variables in the template, which would look like `##VARIABLENAME##`.

I essentially want to grab the `VARIABLENAME` part into an array item, for each variable that exists in the source string.

I looked around a bit but couldn't find anything, regex syntax is quite a beast to someone who hasn't used it before.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

Sample input:

```
"Hello there ##NAME##, you have ##ORDERSNUM## orders pending".
```

Expected output:

```
array[0] = 'NAME'
array[1] = 'ORDERSNUM'
```

I've so far tried

```
preg_match("/#(.*)#/", $temphtml, $tempvars)
```

But this is only returning the first match found, twice.

Comment: show the input string and the expected ouyput

Comment: And you haven't yet tried to tackle the **beast** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular expressions like:

```
preg_match_all('/##([^#]+)##/', $string, $matches)
```

see http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Perfect, this works great, thanks!
Is there any way to only include the contents wrapped within the ##'s? as the return at the moment is including both the "##VAR##" and "var" versions for each find.

Comment: When using the default behavior of preg_match_all, (without setting the optional $flags parameter) you should find the keys collected in the second element of the $matching array, i.e. $matching[1].

Answer (score 0):

Well tackle the **beast** with `/##([^#]*)##/`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU4lD8/2)**

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! As mentioned in the other answer, Is there any way to only include the contents wrapped within the ##'s? as the return at the moment is including both the "##VAR##" and "var" versions for each find.

Comment: @Arcadiax: Do not confuse upvote with answer accept :P You are switching answer accept too much.

Comment: Haha, I thought you could select multiple answers, and since you both gave great answers I wanted to select both. There's my stack noobiness showing :P

Comment: @Arcadiax: That's why there is Up Vote button. To show that you back an answer.

Comment: @Druzion: If I had to **beg** for upvote I would had directly. You should have been here 15 minutes ago. He was changing accept vote so often so I cleared his doubt about **Answer Accept** and **Up Vote**

Comment: @Druzion: You can. Just by telling about it. Like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.6, it's possible to do that:

```
$parts = explode('##', $tpl);
array_pop($parts);
$result = array_values(array_filter($parts, function($v,$k) {
    return ($k&1 && !empty($v));}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this RegEx:

```
##(.*?)##
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/hC0fY3/1)</kbd>

The `.*?` makes the search lazy, so after the first `##`, it will search until it finds another `##`, then stop.

[image: Demo]

---

### To only get the data inside `##`

If you look at [This Demo](https://3v4l.org/a8rrX) on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/a8rrX), you will see that `$matches[1]` has an array of the data stored in the **`1st` Capture Group**. Therefore, on the string:

```
Hello there ##NAME##, you have ##ORDERSNUM## orders pending
```

- `NAME` is stored in [`$matches[1][0]`](https://3v4l.org/qcF5Q)
- `ORDERSNUM` is stored in [`$matches[1][1]`](https://3v4l.org/cobRp)

---

If you use this RegEx:

```
##([^#]*)##
```

[**It will fail**](https://regex101.com/r/nO5aV0/1) on `But ##This#Will#Not#Work## will it?`, however that is not likely to be a variable name. `;)`

Comment: `But ##This#Will#Not#Work## will it?` That's definitely not a variable name .

Answer (score 0):

**You could use [str_ireplace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)**

```
class YourTemplateEngine
{

   /**
    * Set you html content which has all the tags inside
    * @param string $content
    */
   public function setContent($content)
   {
       $this->content = $content;
   }

   /**
    * Set your tags and assign values
    * @param string $tag
    * @param sting | int |number $value
    */
   public function setTagValue($tag, $value)
   {
       $this->tags_array[$tag] = $value;
   }

   /**
    * Replace all tags
    */
   private function replace_tags()
   {
       $tags = array();
       $values = array();
       foreach ($this->tags_array as $tag => $val) {
           array_push($tags, '##'.$tag.'##');
           array_push($values, $val);
       }

       return str_ireplace($tags, $values, $this->content);
   }

   /**
    * Replace all tags and get output
    */
   public function render()
   {
       return $this->replace_tags();
   }
}
```

Then you can just to something like this.

```
$template = new YourTemplateEngine();
$template->setTagValue('NAME','Your Name');
$template->setTagValue('ORDERSNUM',100);
$template->setContent("Hello there ##NAME##, you have ##ORDERSNUM## orders pending");
print $template->render(); 
// Outputs 
// Hello there Your Name, you have 100 orders pending
```